# changing List of list like matrix

Tags: python, arrays, list

Hi so I have a function that takes in 4 parameter first being a nested list that is a matrix and second which is the starting point ex: [1,0], third being a stopping point ex[2,0] and the last parameter that changes the nested list value between the start and stop point ex:-1. So it changes anything from [1,0] to [2,0] based on delta in the example -1 So from [1,0]:[2:0] all numbers subtract by 1

So for now I created the new stopping point and new starting point of the nested list and i'm trying to make it so that the loop will only go through the starting and stopping point and changing any numbers in between. Such as update_elevation(THREE_BY_THREE, [1, 0], [1, 1], -2) to [[1, 2, 1], [2, 4, 5], [7, 8, 9]] So kind of stuck on adding the delta to the new list

Example

```
>>> THREE_BY_THREE_COPY = [[1, 2, 1],[4, 6, 5],[7, 8, 9]]
>>> update_elevation(THREE_BY_THREE_COPY, [1, 0], [1, 1], -2)
>>> THREE_BY_THREE_COPY
[[1, 2, 1], [2, 4, 5], [7, 8, 9]]

def update_elevation(elevation_map, start, stop, delta) -> None:

    new_start = elevation_map[start[0]][start[1]]
    new_stop = elevation_map[stop[0]][stop[1]]
    for num in range(new_start, new_stop):
        num += delta
```

Comment: Why have you used a type annotation indicating that the function returns None, when you have a return statement? (also just check your indenting)

Comment: Also, why have you asked the same question at least 3X today?

Comment: Sorry I got frustrated after being stuck on this code for awhile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For numeric stuff, `numpy` is usually the way to go. We can easily index between start and stop with `arrays`, simplifying the code a lot :)

```
import numpy as np

def update_elevation(elevation_map, start, stop, delta):
    elevation_map = np.array(elevation_map)
    elevation_map[start[0]:stop[0] + 1, start[1]:stop[1] + 1] += delta
    return elevation_map


THREE_BY_THREE_COPY = [[1, 2, 1],
                       [4, 6, 5],
                       [7, 8, 9]]

print(update_elevation(THREE_BY_THREE_COPY, [1, 0], [1, 1], -2))
```

I would recommend trying not to use the list of lists for these kinds of problems, as arrays are often much easier to work with.

**edit**
A solution without numpy:

```
def update_elevation(elevation_map, start, stop, delta):
    for xval in range(start[0], stop[0] + 1):
        for yval in range(start[1], stop[1] + 1):
            elevation_map[xval][yval] += delta
    return elevation_map
```

Comment: Would it be possible to just use loops for this without import np? I think for my code I got up to the specific range of the section for start and stop but just implementing the delta to the list i'm stuck on

Comment: sure, give me a sec

Comment: @itachi123 sth like this?

Comment: yes! thank you! I was stuck on this for days! much appreciated

Comment: is this a common math problem?

Comment: @CătălinGeorgeFeștilă what do you mean?

Comment: is this a common math problem, like tower-of-Hanoi https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-program-for-tower-of-hanoi/?

Comment: I don't think so. However I've wanted to update a rectangular area in a matrix many times before, so in that sense it is a common (programming) problem. Just not a math problem. :)

Answer (score 1):

To just use loops you can use the following sample:

```
def update_elevation(elevation_map, start, stop, delta):

    for i in range(start[0], stop[0]+1):
        for j in range(start[1], stop[1]+1):
            elevation_map[i][j] += delta
```